# Sorting list of shared pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, bind

Given the class

```
class objects {
  public:
    bool compareArea (const objects& obj) const { return this->area < obj.area; }
  private:
    double area;
};
```

I want to sort a

```
list<shared_ptr<objects>> myObjects;
```

I cannot use a lambda (since my toolchain's C++11 support is incomplete). Thus, I tried the following:

```
using namespace placeholders;
myObjects.sort(bind(&objects::compareArea,_1,_2));
```

This line is called from another file (not from a class member!). The problem is, that `compareArea` requires two `objects` as input. But I give two shared pointer to `objects` to it. Is there an easy way of how to include the dereferencing of the pointers **into** the `sort`-call? I want the `objects::compareArea(..)` function to stay as it is. I do **not** want this kind of solution

```
bool compareArea (const shared_ptr<objects>& ptr1, const shared_ptr<objects>& ptr2) {
  return ptr1->area > ptr2->area;
}

// in same source-file:
myObjects.sort(bind(compareArea,_1,_2));
```

where `compareArea` is no member-function of `objects`. Actually an operator overloading of `<` would be my favourite solution.

Comment: Which `bind` and `placeholders` are you using? That could also have support for expressions of the sort you need.

Comment: How about `bool lessObject(const shared_ptr<objects>&lhs, const shared_ptr<objects>& rhs) { return lhs->compareArea(*rhs); }` ?

Comment: @Angew I don't quite get your question...I'm using std::bind and the placeholders are `_1 ` and `_2` as written in the code snippet above.

Comment: @Kapa11 `std::bind` and `std::placeholders` were introduced in C++11. How are you using them without C++11 support??

Comment: @Angew ok I got your point. I'm compiling with `-std=c++0x`. Thus, I can use these features but I am not able to use features like e.g. lambda or `override`,`final`,...

Comment: @Kapa11 OK, makes sense. However, given the current year and compiler versions, you should probably also consider upgrading.

Comment: @Angew Yeah, I know and I also requested that several times. But admin says no to it, for some reason I am not able to understand :/

Comment: @Kappa11 Why is the admin making decisions which directly affect a developer's way of working and productivity? This should be discussed with and decided by a manager, not by IT.

Comment: @Angew: You're totally right. I talked to my boss s.t. he can talk to the admins. The answer I got is that it is not possible. I hammer on this point several times...I hope somewhen I will achieve my goal. The problem is that I'm just one person of really few using C++. Other colleagues use other languages or software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you never store any kind of pointer in a container.

Instead, make a handle class which supports the required arithmetic and comparison operators.

It makes for code that's easier to reason about:

```
class objects {
public:
    objects(double w, double h) : area(w * h) {}

    bool operator<(const objects& r) const { return this->area < r.area; }
private:
    double area;
};


struct object_handle
{
    object_handle(shared_ptr<objects> const& ptr) : ptr_(ptr) {}

    static object_handle create(double w, double h) { return make_shared<objects>(w,h); }

    bool operator < (object_handle const& r) const {
        return *ptr_ < *r.ptr_;
    }
    shared_ptr<objects> ptr_;
};


int main() {
    std::vector<object_handle> mylist;
    mylist.push_back(object_handle::create(10, 7));
    mylist.push_back(object_handle::create(2, 5));
    std::sort(mylist.begin(), mylist.end());
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't I store pointers in a container? Often, I just store shared pointers in lists where no arithmetic operations on the items are requested. Where is the disadvantage to do it the way I did before?

Comment: when we operate on shared pointers, we almost always want to operate on the thing that the pointer is pointing to, not the pointer itself. So it makes sense to abstract away the details of how an object is held. We can then talk the handle's interface in a meaningful way (sort, +, -, less than, do_something, etc) without worrying about the details of how the reference is being held. If we later change our minds about the implementation of the handle (i.e unique_ptrs, or no pointers at all) we only have to change code in one place.

Comment: Ok, you convinced me... I will do that in the future. But if we only want to dereference the pointers in a container and not want to do any arithmetic operations on it, then such a handle would increase code unnecessary (even if it's much easier to expand the datastructure).

Comment: But I totally agree, your code snippet is really nice :)

Comment: @Kapa11 sure. if you're literally just storing pointers (to ensure lifetime extension, for example) then do what makes most logical sense. I like to write code from the point of view of the guy who has to make sense of the narrative when reading it.

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas are just syntactic sugar for a class with `operator()`, so you can very easily write one directly (especially if you don't need captures):

```
struct Comparator
{
  bool operator() (const shared_ptr<objects> &lhs, const shared_ptr<objects> &rhs) const
  {
    return lhs->compareArea(*rhs);
  }
};

myObjects.sort(Comparator());
```

Comment: This works. I also replaced the function `compareArea(..)` by overloading the `>` operator in `objects`. So I just returned `(*lhs) > (*rhs)`.